# How to save max duration with sharedpref in flutter?

Tags: flutter, duration

I tried to save duration with sharedpreference only if my last duration is superior to the current duration and so show the MAX duration. my problem is that I don't know how to compare two string duration.

here is the code thanks (@ZeRj)

```
  load_lastPressString()async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {

      final lastPressString = prefs.getString("lastButtonPress");
      _lastButtonPress = lastPressString!=null ? DateTime.parse(lastPressString) : DateTime.now();
      _updateTimer();
      _ticker = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:1),(_)=>_updateTimer());
    });
  }


  save_lastPressString()async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      prefs.setString('_lastButtonPress', _lastButtonPress.toIso8601String());
    });
  }

  void _updateTimer() {
    final duration = DateTime.now().difference(_lastButtonPress);
    final newDuration = _formatDuration(duration);
    setState(() {
      _pressDuration = newDuration;
    });
  }

  String _formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) {
      if (n >= 10) return "$n";
      return "0$n";
    }

    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return "${twoDigits(duration.inDays)}:${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";


  }
```

---

I tried the code bellow, but I can't use > with string and tried to parse int but not possible with date, and I tried to extract each decimal with regex but it's to complicated and I have errors I havn't understand.

```
  save_max_lastPress()async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {

if(_lastButtonPress>Max_lastButtonPress)
               {
        prefs.setString('_max_lastPress', Max_lastButtonPress)    ;

           }
       }
     ); 
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you have to save the maximal as the duration.

Use `prefs.setInt("maxDuration",maxDuration.toSeconds())` to save it as a int in shared preferences and load it with

```
Duration(seconds: prefs.getInt("maxDuration")
```

You can simply compare two instances of Duration.

I edited the last example to implement this feature:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterfly/SharedPrefs.dart';
import 'package:flutterfly/SharedPrefs.dart' as prefix0;

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestWidgetState createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  DateTime _lastButtonPress;
  String _pressDuration;
  Timer _ticker;
  Duration _maxDuration;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Time since button pressed"),
          Text(_pressDuration),
          Text("Maximal Duration"),
          Text(_formatDuration(_maxDuration)),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Press me"),
            onPressed: () {
              _lastButtonPress = DateTime.now();
              _updateTimer();
              sharedPreferences.setString("lastButtonPress",_lastButtonPress.toIso8601String());
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //load max duration, if there is none start with 0
    _maxDuration = Duration(seconds:sharedPreferences.getInt("maxDuration")??0);
    final lastPressString = sharedPreferences.getString("lastButtonPress");
    _lastButtonPress = lastPressString!=null ? DateTime.parse(lastPressString) : DateTime.now();
    _updateTimer();
    _ticker = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:1),(_)=>_updateTimer());
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _ticker.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }



  void _updateTimer() {
    final duration = DateTime.now().difference(_lastButtonPress);
    //check for new max duration here
    Duration newMaxDuration = _maxDuration;
    if(duration> _maxDuration) {
      //save when current duration is a new max
      newMaxDuration = duration;
      sharedPreferences.setInt("maxDuration",newMaxDuration.inSeconds);
    }
    final newDuration =_formatDuration(duration);
    setState(() {
      _maxDuration = newMaxDuration;
      _pressDuration = newDuration;
    });
  }

  String _formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) {
      if (n >= 10) return "$n";
      return "0$n";
    }

    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return "${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
  }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I search, with this code it stop the counter when the max duration is trigger. I want let the current timer working, but if I press another time the button ,display a new variable with the max duration. the goal is to display always max duration between all durations record. Sorry if i'm not clear :)

Comment: Sorry, got your intention wrong. I edited my answer with a new example

Comment: @ZeRj do you know how to set expired time inside shared preferences instead of using Duration?.. for example... the data inside shared preferences will expired at 11:00:00

Comment: @uyhaW use the date.toIso8601String() function and store the string in shared preferences. Use DateTime.parse() to recover the date from the string.